# stop the processes started by the rtd command

Tags: meteor

I have installed [RTD from xolvio](https://github.com/xolvio/rtd) and it works fine until you want to stop it.

Expecting a meteor or meteorite behaviour, I pressed CTRL+C to stop the process. The `mrt` command and the mongo instance are still running. So is the selenium server.

There are no indications on how to stop the thing in the documentation. It must be something I'm missing.

thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is as simple as running `grunt bgShell:killAll`

I had to make some changes to the `killall` function in `rtd/Gruntfile.js` in order to make it  work on Mac OS 10.7.5:

- replace `ps -ef`with `ps -A`
- it appears that the process number is not at the same place. replacing `print $2` with `print $1` does the trick.

hope that helps someone